# How to tell jetty-maven-plugin what version of jetty to run?

Tags: maven, plugins, jetty, elasticsearch

I want to tell jetty-maven-plugin what version of jetty I want it to run, e.g. 8.1.4 instead of 9.0.0. I don't see it anywhere [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html)

Also, the next step I want is to tell this plugin to use specific plugins that I have configured on top of my jetty. Is this possible?

I have essentially edited the [elasticsearch-jetty](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty) plugin and want to run that through jetty and maven using this plugin, or really anything that works. Does anyone have any idea/help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use maven jetty plugin, jetty is hosting your application and you need to start jetty first in order to run your application. In elasticsearch-jetty plugin it's other way around, elasticsearch is hosting jetty. So, in order to run elasticsearch with elasticsearch-jetty from maven, you need to start elasticsearch, not jetty. I would consider using [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following to your `<pluginManagement>` section

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
    </plugin>
```

Obviously change the version to the exact version you want to run.

Alternatively from the CLI

```
mvn org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.8.v20121106:run
```

The plugin changed groupId from `org.mortbay.jetty` to `org.eclipse.jetty` with the 9.x releases

Comment: I started with the same idea of being the same version of Jetty but the decision was based on guesswork and not on version notes.

Answer (score 0):

Here (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-helloworld.html#configuring-embedded-jetty-with-maven) the jetty version is in the pom dependencies section.

If that doesn't work right, you might try dependencies inside the plugin section for the jetty plugin. There is some info here (http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/)

Or you could try to use an old version of the plugin.